# Function.prototype.bind in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function like so:

```
function foo(){

}
```

I can make this call:

```
foo().bind(self);
```

why does Javascript let me do that without a runtime error?

I thought the only valid syntax for this was:

```
 var func = foo.bind(self);
 func();
```

in shorthand, that's:

```
foo.bind(self)();
```

futhermore, I thought that something like this was possible:

```
function foo(){

}.bind(self);
```

but that last one doesn't appear to work

Comment: `foo().bind(self);` will work only if `foo` is returning another function like `function foo(){... return function(){};}`

Comment: the last one will work if you wrap the function declaration in parens. `(function foo(){}).bind(self)`

Comment: The `foo.bind(self)()` 'shorthand' is a little silly as well, since you could just `foo.call(self)`. No need to create a new function if you're invoking it instantly.

Comment: *"without a runtime error"* Uhm, I get `TypeError: foo(...) is undefined` . `function foo(){ }.bind(self);` only works if the function definition is interpreted as function expression.

Comment: I get runtime error as well. Your example is either missing something or your browser is buggy. What browser/interpreter are you running on?

Comment: I think I was in Mozilla when I was debugging it

Answer (score 0):

`foo().bind(self);` is allowed at compilation but may throw if `foo()` doesn't return a function object. Like this

```
function bar() {
}

function foo(){
    return bar;
}
```

So `bind` will actually execute for `bar`;

And last one is function declaration so you can't use dot notation. To make it possible you need to convert it to an expression. Easiest way is to add braces

```
(function foo(){

}.bind(self));
```

However this is useless as you can't store the result. If you assign it to `func` your function declaration will become an expression. The the following at least makes sense:

```
var func;
func = function foo(){

}.bind(self);
```